# Can the sigmoid function approximate any function (or relation) where $0<y<1$

Tags: analysis, functions, regression

I'm studying Machine Learning and Artificial Neural Networks. Some basic principles of Machine Learning are linear regression, multivariate linear regression, and nonlinear regression. The last of these, nonlinear regression, involves fitting a curve to a set of data. This curve can be any shape (it might fail the vertical and horizontal line test).

In the tutorial I am following, Stanford Machine Learning by Andrew Ng, he says that the sigmoid function is used for non linear regression, and the more polynomial terms used the more complex the curve can be.

I'll give an example:

$$y=\frac{1}{1+e^{-\left(100x^2-100y\right)}}$$

approximates the polynomial:

$$y=x^2$$

The sigmoid function can also approximate curves that are relations instead of functions. For example:

$$y=\space \frac{1}{1+e^{-\left(5+1x\space -3y\space +4xy\space -1yx^2\space -2yx^3-1xy^2\space +30y^3\right)}}$$

But if I use enough polynomial terms can this function approximate **any** function or relation?

It seems like this needs to be true otherwise the sigmoid function would be a bad choice of hypothesis for nonlinear regression.

Comment: You surely mean 0<y<1

Comment: Yes, i've corrected that now, thanks.

Comment: Do you need an interpolation polynomial (going through some number of points) or an approximation of the function in the whole interval ?

Comment: It doesn't need to exactly go through any points. I need to minimise a cost function using the data and the hypothesis, which is the sigmoid function. e.g Given a set of data: (1,1) (2,4) (3,8) (4,17) (5,23) (6,38), It needs to minimise the difference between the y values of these points and the y values at the points x=1 x=2 x=3 x=4 x=5 x=6 on the sigmoid curve.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure to well understand what is really needed.

With your example given a set of data: (1,1) (2,4) (3,8) (4,17) (5,23) (6,38) one can compute approximately the parameters of the sigmoid or logistic functions thanks to available softwares for non linear regression. Another method which isn't iterative and which doesn't need to set some initial values of parameters can be used. Example below :

[image]

[image]

The maximum of y (found around 87) is very doubtful because there is no points given in the range of large x. In this case the value of L is strongly dependant of the scatter on the low x points. Also with only a few points at low x the value of L depends a lot on the criteria of fitting (LMSE, LMAE, LMSRE, etc.) which is not clearly specified in the wording of the question.

For more accuracy according to a specified criteria of fitting the above method is not sufficient. One have to use a software for non-linear regression. Then the values of the parameters found above can be used as good initial values for starting the iterative process.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $ y $ is the variable you're trying to approximate, I don't think it's correct to include terms involving $ y $ in the polynomial. The point of regression is to estimate $ y $ for new data where we don't know it in advance.

In linear and logistic regression, we also assume $ y $ is a function of $ x $ (plus some randomness), so we can reduce to just thinking about functions, not general relations.

Let's consider the set of points $ (x, \sigma^{-1}(y)) $ for each of point $ (x, y) $ of your dataset, where $ \sigma $ is the sigmoid function and $ \sigma^{-1} $ is its inverse. If you're interested in fitting the data, then assuming no repeated $ x $-values, the [Interpolation Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_interpolation) says you can find a polynomial $ p(x) $ passing exactly through the points. That won't necessarily be the best approximation to the true function underlying the data though, because you may be overfitting.

Now consider $ \sigma(p(x)) $ on a closed, bounded interval that contains all the $ 
x $-values. This passes through all the data points $ (x, y) $. By the [Stone-Weierstrass Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem), This can be approximated to any desired accuracy by a polynomial in $ p(x) $, which is just a polynomial in $ x $, say $ q(x) $. $ q(x) $ can be made as close as you want to all the data points by choosing a high enough degree. In most cases, a single polynomial never minimises the cost function, it's just that as you add more and more polynomial terms, the loss decreases more and more.